# How to validate both attribute together in Yii 1.x

Tags: php, validation, yii

I have an issue in `Yii1.x (1.1.14)`, but I haven't yet find a solution for it.

In my form, I have two text fields, [Text Field A] and [Text Field B]. I want to validate both of them together follow rules below:

1. If A && B empty, return 1 error required message.
   Ex: Verifying username and password, one of them does not right, output 1 message for both: Your username or password not right.
2. If A || B available, validate numerical of attribute which is available. It also means If both are available, validate numerical both.

I have tried to use custom validation, but it validated each attribute. Therefore, I can't validate both of them together.

*Does anyone know a solution for this issue?*

Comment: Yii does not have validation rule for combination of fields. So I think you need to do manual validation and generate error message manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own validator. Just add a method to your model:

```
/**
 * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
 */
public function rules()
{
    return  array(
        'A',
        'requiredIf',
        'isSet' => 'B'
   );

/**
 * Validator-Rule
 * @param string $attribute 
 * @param array $params 
 */
public function requiredIf($attribute, $params){
    //validate
    $isSet = $params['isSet'];
    if(! empty($isSet)) {
        $attr = $this->{$isSet};
        $other = $this->{$attribute};
        if(! empty($attr) && empty($other)) {
            $this->addError($attribute, 'Error Text');
        }
    }
}
```

This validator will throw a error when B ist set, but A isnt.